# Visual Studio Error: "Cannot resolve 'GenXbf.dll' under path...Please install the latest version of the Windows 10 Software Development Kit"

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2019

After unsuccessfully attempting to run a Windows Template Studio project/solution using the "Local Machine" button within Visual Studio 2019, I received the following error message in the error list:

*Cannot resolve 'GenXbf.dll' under path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17134.0\x86\genxbf.dll'.  Please install the latest version of the Windows 10 Software Development Kit.*

I would like to know what the source of this error is, as I have already tried manually updating the SDK.  Is it possible that some part of the project or visual studio does not work because of a recent Windows Update?

Thank you,

Lee

Comment: Have you verified the presence of that file on your filesystem?  Does the program have permissions to it?

Comment: "I have already tried manually updating the SDK." - Which versions of the Windows SDK do you have installed other than the `Windows 10 (10.0.17134.0) SDK`?  My suggestion would be to remove all versions of the Windows 10 SDK you have installed, reinstall `10.0.17134.0`, and see if the issue continues.  [Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886939/vs2017-cannot-resolve-genxbf-dll).  If you still have the problem.  Edit your question and include the vital information.  Include screenshots of which components you have installed from the SDK.

Comment: @Ramhound After reading your comment, I found out, through the visual studio installer, that I had two versions of the Windows 10 SDK installed:  10.0.17763.0 and 10.0.18362.0.  I uninstalled 10.0.17763.0, reloaded visual studio, and successfully ran my project application on my machine.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know what the source of this error is, as I have already tried manually updating the SDK?

The error is caused by your Windows SDK installation being corrupt and/or incomplete.  Based on your comment that you have multiple versions of the Windows SDK installed, it sounds like Visual Studio, is not configured to use the correct version of the Windows SDK.

Visual Studio becomes self-aware of which versions of the SDK that are installed, the simplest solution to your problem, is to uninstall the versions you no longer required and/or reinstall all versions of the Windows 10 SDK through the Visual Studio installer.

> Is it possible that some part of the project or visual studio does not work because of a recent Windows Update?

There is nothing that would have been served through Windows Update that would have caused this problem, however, an update to Visual Studio 2019 could have caused this issue.

Background: [VS2017 Cannot resolve GenXbf.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886939/vs2017-cannot-resolve-genxbf-dll)

Comment: I actually figured this out and uninstalled an earlier version before I even saw your answer, but I am grateful that you did answer.  Visual Studio is now functioning properly.